# Javascript: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, dom, events, onclick, typeerror

I know, there are many threads covering this topic. BUT I didn't figure out yet, why the console is still showing the error.


**The Plan**

When I click on `input#submit`, I want `main_jobBot.js` to switch from `index.html` to `https://www.google.de/`.


**Summary**

I am trying to call the function `change` by the `btn.onclick` event.

It works fine, when I place the OnClick Event inside of the `<input>` tag.

But when I place it directly into the `main_jobBot.js`, I get the following Error:


**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at main_jobBot.js:7
```

**I have...**

- ...checked the link to the `main_jobBot.js`.
- ...tried to move the script to the end of the `index.html` in order to make sure, every element was loaded, that the `main_jobBot.js` might need.
- ...tried to rename all my components to make sure, there is no default variable or method, I accidentally used.
- ...double checked the code for typing errors.

***Note:*** I am an absolute beginner to Javascript as well as to Stackoverflow!



**MAIN_JOBBOT.JS and INDEX.HTML**

```js
/* main_jobBot.js */

let btn = document.getElementById("submit");

function change() {
  location.replace("https://www.google.de/");
}

btn.onclick = change;
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<input type="submit" value="Let J.A.B. find the Job!" id="submit">
</input>
```

**FINAL EDIT: Now I've got it! I had to remove the `#` AND move the script to the End of the HTML file!**

Comment: Just remove `#` character from `document.getElementById("#submit")`. It should work.

Comment: I removed it and tried it again, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What *doesn't work* mean? Any error?

Comment: Nothing changed. The console is showing me the same error as before:

```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at main_jobBot.js:7```

Comment: Note - `input` element is a `self-closing` tag. i:e `<input />`

Comment: Is the `MAIN_JOBBOT.JS` file loaded before the `input`? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959)

Comment: @adiga Yes, it is. But like I said I tried to move it to the end. But it makes no difference in my case.

Comment: Check the link in previous comment. Either wrap the the code in `window.onload = function() {  let btn = ... }` or move the file to the bottom

Comment: Either your selector is wrong, or you're running the Javascript too early. Both of those situations (and their fixes) are described in the canonical question.

Comment: Thank You guys for all Your answers, but I read this post and tried the solutions, which are described there. Sadly none of them worked out for me. That's why I wanted to present my individual problem.

Answer (score -1):

Any character used when refering to an element in your html using Javascript or any language at that can have an affect on how your code functions. Remove the `#` from the variable and this will work - oh and also, just a suggestion but when changing your `url`, try using:

`location.href="https://www.google.de/"`

Other than that this is fantastic, great work!